# How to add pagination for wishlist products in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get products on the page-wise for wishlist collection. I was getting a count for product collections in the below code. I have set the page size to one but it's showing the product count two. Please help me to fix this. Thanks.

```
                    $wishlist1 = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true)
                        ->setCurPage($page_num)
                        ->setPageSize(1)
                        ->load();

                foreach($wishlist1->getItemCollection() as $product){
                    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product['product_id']);//product id here
                    echo $product['product_id'];
                }
```

Comment: Hi @sudhakar-sj, please check my solution. I could not notice your comment in my related answer on Magento SE.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code:

```
<?php
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail('mohit@streammarket.co.uk');
$wishlistItems = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                ->setWebsiteId($customer->getWebsiteId())
                ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
                ->setCurPage(1)
                ->setPageSize(1)
                ->load();
?>
```